# How to use bindTo in PHP

Tags: php

it is not exactly a question, but I found a following example and I can't understand how does it work, can someone explain it?

```
<?php
class Number {
    private $v = 0;
    
    public function __construct($v) {
        $this->v = $v;
    }
    
    public function mul() {
        return function ($x) {
            return $this->v * $x; 
        };
    }
}

$one = new Number(1);
$two = new Number(2);
$double = $two->mul()->bindTo($one);
echo $double(5);
```

I understand the code, but putting together it doesn't make sanse to me. The answer should be 5 btw.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in your question is a bit more complicated than it needs to be to just explain how `bindTo` works. I assume the point is that you can **re**-bind `$this`, rather than just binding an object to a closure, but I think that probably makes everything a bit harder to understand.

The whole idea is that for a given closure, you can create a clone for which you have set the surrounding scope. The simplest example would be something like this ([demo here](https://3v4l.org/NEOpN)):

```
$closureThatShowsTheProperty = function() {
    echo $this->prop;
};

$objectThatHasTheProperty = new class() {
    public $prop = 123;
};

$closureThatShowsTheProperty->bindTo($objectThatHasTheProperty)();
```

> 123

Note that the class and the function are completely independent until the call to `bindTo`. Your example is demonstrating that even a closure that is generated within an instance of a class can be rebound to a different instance, but that's probably not the most common use-case.

One difference is that a closure generated within an existing class instance will have that class as its scope, so will allow accessing private + protected properties. If you wanted to replicate that using an anonymous function from elsewhere in your code, you would need to use the second argument to `bindTo` to set the scope:

```
$closureThatShowsTheProperty = function() {
    echo $this->prop;
};

$objectThatHasTheProperty = new class() {
    private $prop = 123;
};

$closureThatShowsTheProperty->bindTo($objectThatHasTheProperty)();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property...

```
$closureThatShowsTheProperty->bindTo($objectThatHasTheProperty, $objectThatHasTheProperty)();
```

> 123